# Besides syntax, is there any difference between a normal function and an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've recently begun using ECMAScript 2016's arrow functions instead of the original syntax to define functions. Would it be ok if I just used this syntax every time I wanted to define a function, or are are there any disadvantages like speed, etc.?

```
(function(){
  alert('Is this');
})();

(()=>{
  alert('somehow better than this?')
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

One thing to note is that an arrow function does not have use of the `arguments` object.

```js
let test = () => {
  // expect an error
  console.log(arguments);
}

test(1,2,3);
```

- Arrow functions lexically bind `this`
- You cannot use `new` on an arrow function:

```js
let Person = (name) => {
  this.name = name;
}
   
// expect an error
let person = new Person('Bob');
```

There are many differences, I would check some of the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) on arrow functions.

Comment: I also noticed that firefox uses 2-3x more time with arrow functions, but i just did a quick perf test.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions are always anonymous and have [lexical this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this). Differences in performance should be negligible but `this` might refer to something unexpected (or maybe it refers to exactly what you expect and you won't have to bind).