# Is there a difference between a function and an arrow (=>) function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, hoisting

I've been playing around ES6 features for sometime now and on this very occasion, there was an error of me using the function before declaring it, but when I changed to the good old traditional way, the error wasn't caught.

Does function hoisting only work for the traditional way, or there's a catch I'm missing?

I've tried searching but this [Besides syntax, is there any difference between a normal function and an arrow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530922/besides-syntax-is-there-any-difference-between-a-normal-function-and-an-arrow-f) couldn't give me a satisfactory result

A simple input form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hero Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="hero">
    <label for="heroName">Name:
      <input type="text" name="heroName" autofocus
      placeholder="Your super Hero Name"Smaxlength="32">
    <!-- </label> -->
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
  // Throws an error when called first
  form.addEventListener('submit', makeHero, false);
  const form = document.forms.hero;

  const makeHero = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const hero = {};
    hero.name = form.heroName.value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(hero), hero, 'clear');
    return hero;
  }
</script>
```

```
<script>
  const form = document.forms.hero;

  const makeHero = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const hero = {};
    hero.name = form.heroName.value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(hero), hero, 'clear');
    return hero;
  }
// Works fine after arrow function declaration
  form.addEventListener('submit', makeHero, false);
</script>
```

Comment: arrow function aren’t hoisted, so you need to put that `form.addEventListener('submit', makeHero, false);` at the bottom.

Comment: Arrow functions are clearly just values being assigned to regular variables. `function` declarations on the other hand are a completely different kind of statement, and they're hoisted.

Comment: "Does function hoisting only work for the traditional way, or there's a catch I'm missing?" — You've **demonstrated** that function declarations are hoisted and arrow function assignments to constants are not. It's unclear why you feel the need to ask this as a question.

Answer (score 0):

This really has nothing to do with arrow functions, per se. In JavaScript, **declarations** are hoisted to the top of their scope. A declaration might look like this:

```
let x = 42;
```

But, there are really two things being done with this single statement. First, the declaration:

```
let x
```

And then the assignment:

```
x = 42
```

Here, the declaration (`let x`) is hoisted, **but not the assignment** (`x = 42`).

This is no different than what you are doing with your variable declaration that you are doing with your variable being assigned to an arrow function:

```
const makeHero = (event) => { ...
```

The `const makeHero` will be hoisted, but not the assignment of: `makeHero = (event) => { ...

Functions can be set up in more than just one way though and one such way is a [***Function Declaration***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), which doesn't assign a variable and the entire function is hoisted:

```
function makeHero(event) {
}
```

Now a [Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), is just an expression where a function is being assigned as the value of something else and that's what you are doing with your assignment of the arrow function to the constant `hero`. So, `const hero` gets hoisted, but not the assignment, so if you were to try to call `hero` before the assignment, you'd get an error.